# Facing Import Error when importing esda and libpysal libraries

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, gis, geospatial

Even though I have installed both the libraries several times using different orders in different virtual environments, I'm still facing an issue where I'm not able to import and use certain geospatial libraries like esda and libpysal. The following error shows up:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SLAADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_35328/2667884714.py in <module>
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 import esda
      6 import libpysal as lps
      7 import pysal

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\esda\__init__.py in <module>
      5 
      6 """
----> 7 from . import adbscan
      8 from .gamma import Gamma
      9 from .geary import Geary

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\esda\adbscan.py in <module>
      8 import pandas
      9 import numpy as np
---> 10 from libpysal.cg.alpha_shapes import alpha_shape_auto
     11 from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
     12 from collections import Counter

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\libpysal\__init__.py in <module>
     25     Tools for creating and manipulating weights
     26 """
---> 27 from . import cg
     28 from . import io
     29 from . import weights

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\libpysal\cg\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from .sphere import *
     10 from .voronoi import *
---> 11 from .alpha_shapes import *

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\libpysal\cg\alpha_shapes.py in <module>
     22 
     23 try:
---> 24     import pygeos
     25 
     26     HAS_PYGEOS = True

c:\users\sla admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pygeos\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .lib import GEOSException  # NOQA
      2 from .lib import Geometry  # NOQA
      3 from .lib import geos_version, geos_version_string  # NOQA
      4 from .lib import geos_capi_version, geos_capi_version_string  # NOQA
      5 from .decorators import UnsupportedGEOSOperation  # NOQA

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Would really appreciate any help in making this work. Please throw any suggestions you might have at me.

Answer (score 0):

install pygeos i.e conda install pygeos
it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue when running example code from a couple of years ago. The pysal API has changed.

Import libpysal first then import the esda libraries eg

```
import libpysal
from esda.moran import Moran
from esda.smaup import Smaup
```

see
https://pysal.org/esda/generated/esda.Moran.html